# c# csv sorting a list using third columns

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that opens a CSV file using StreamReader and creates a table with 4 columns and rows for however many rows are in the CSV file. This works correctly as is creating the output of:

> Item Code, Item Description, Current Count, On Order
>
> A0001, Toy Car, 4, Yes
>
> A0002, Toy Truck, 1, No

I save all the data from the CSV file in a global list without splitting each line. When I am creating the table I split the lines using "Split(',')", which works as needed at the time. However I am unsure how to reorder the whole list using the Current Count column from largest to smallest. I have tried the following but it give an error on the Split(',').

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static List<string> items = new List<string>();
}
private void createTableWithOrder(int order)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Globals.items.; i++)
    {
         var values = Globals.items[i].Split(',');

         if (order == 1)
         {
              values = Globals.items[i].OrderBy(itemDesc => itemDesc.Split(',')).ToList();
         }
    }
}
```

The Error given is below:

> 'char' does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2):

The `OrderBy` call is working on all *characters* in the string at `Globals.items[i]`. That is why you're seeing the current error.
In order to sort the entire collection the order by needs to be made on the list as a whole, e.g:

```
var values = Globals.items.Select(line => line.Split(',')); // Select columns for all rows
var orderedListOfValues = values
    .OrderByDescending(cols => int.TryParse(cols[2].Trim(), out var order) ? order : int.MaxValue); // Sort  by count as an integer
```

Note that in the above example sorting on non-numeric values (e.g. heading) will use the maximum value of an integer.
Depending on the expected outcome, these results can then be merged back into a list of strings for presentation:

```
var orderedItems = string.Join(",", orderedListOfValues)
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I add your code it throws an error `The name 'var' does not exist in the current context` for "out var order)" and im not sure how to use this to split it for my table ie I used to do `Label itemCodeData = new Label(); itemCodeData.Text = values[0].ToString();` but if i add the orderedListOfValues instead of values[0] it gives me `System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable 2[System.String[],System.Int32]` as the output.

Comment: The syntax used (`out var order`) is relatively new in C# and may not be supported in your project. Declaring the variable before the `OrderByDescending` statement can resolve this (i.e. `var order = -1;` and using `int.TryParse(cols[2].Trim(), out order)`. A little more context would help in giving more to the point suggestions if you have more specific requirements with regard to the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have stored the list will not help you to generate a table with sorting capability. To solve your problem instead of `List<string>` you should create a model(IItem interface and Item class) using those models create List. Then before rendering the table you can sort the List on whatever column you like.

```
List<IItem> items = new List<Item>();
items.Add({itemCode: excelData.itemCode , itemDescription: excelData.itemDescription,itemCount: excelData.itemCount, orderCount:excelData.orderCount});
List<IItem> itemsToCreateTable = items.OrderBy(o=>o.itemCount).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is no clear why you would not simply make a “Class” of the items in the file. With a “Class” you can sort the items any way you choose and in numerous ways. In addition, it appears the column you want to sort by (Current Count) is a NUMBER. If you sort numbers as `strings`, you will get all the 1’s together, 2’s together etc. Example it would look something like.

1

10

100

2

20

3

4
…

You will not get the proper NUMERICAL sort order using strings. Therefore, you must sort the column by the number and not the string to get the correct numerical order. The idea behind using a class is it gives you full control over the sorting. If you make a `List` of `Item` and the `Item` class implements the `IComparable` interface, the sorting could be done with one line of code… `Items.Sort().`

Below is an example of what is described above. First the “Class” `Item` to hold the objects in the file. It contains only the properties need for this example, namely the `CompareTo` method which will get used when you call `Items.Sort().`

```
public class Item : IComparable {

  public string Code { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public int Count { get; set; }
  public bool OnOrder { get; set; }

  public Item(string code, string description, int count, bool onOrder) {
    Code = code;
    Description = description;
    Count = count;
    OnOrder = onOrder;
  }

  public int CompareTo(object obj) {
    Item that = (Item)obj;
    return Count.CompareTo(that.Count);
  } 
}
```

Below is an example of using the `Item` class to SORT the list by the “Current Count” column. A `DataGridView` is used to display the sorted list.

```
List<Item> Items;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Items = GetData();
  Items.Sort();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = Items;
}

private List<Item> GetData() {
  List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
  Item newItem;
  string line;
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"D:\Test\Test22.csv")) {
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
      if ((newItem = GetItemFromString(line)) != null) {
        items.Add(newItem);
      }
    }
  }
  return items;
}

private Item GetItemFromString(string itemString) {
  string[] splitArray = itemString.Split(',');
  bool onOrder;
  int count = 0;
  if (splitArray.Length >= 4) {
    int.TryParse(splitArray[2].Trim(), out count);
    if (splitArray[3].Trim() == "Yes")
      onOrder = true;
    else
      onOrder = false;
    return new Item(splitArray[0].Trim(), splitArray[1].Trim(), count, onOrder);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks promising, however is there a way to use the table that i already have rather than a dataGridView? `Label itemCodeData = new Label();
                itemCodeData.Text = values[0].ToString();
                dynamicTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(itemCodeData, 0, i + 1);` or is there a way to make just the current count column editable?

Comment: Also how could I adjust this to order by "OnOrder" or "Item Code"

Comment: _”… is there a way to use the table that i already have …”_ It is unknow what the table looks like so I don’t know. … _“… is there a way to make just the current count column editable… ”_ Again this is unknown since we don’t know what you are putting the data into. It appears you are adding some of the data to a label which users normally cannot edit. We can see the `List<string>` (values which is editable) but it is unknown how this data is displayed to the user. Are you allowing the user to edit the data?

Comment: You can sort the posted `List<Item>` on any field. `List<Item> sorted = Items.OrderBy(c => c.Code).ToList();` If your needed a `DataTable` instead of a `List<Item>` … I recommend creating a method that takes a `List<Item>` and returns a `DataTable` from the list.

Answer (score 0):

**Not a direct answer to your question. But I think you are writing code that is already available for free.**

I strongly suggest that you use [nuget package CSV Helper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started). It takes any text stream, string, text reader etc, and converts the CSV file into an IEnumerable of the type that you expect. It works with and without a header line containing the columns

```
class MyItem
{
    public string Code {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public int Count {get; set;}
    public bool OnOrder {get; set;}
}
```

Getting all MyItems from the CSV file:

```
string myCsvFileName = ...
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(myCsvFileName))
{
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {    
        IEnumerable<MyItem> items = reader.GetRecords<MyItem>();

        // you can do any Linq with this:
        var allItems = items.ToList();

        // or if you only need some records:
        var unAvailableItems = items.Where(item => item.Count == 0);
    }
}
```

Read the link to see what to do if you have a special separator, a header line, or anything else. It is highly configurable.